# Using a specific column in a Datatable

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datatable

I have a stored procedure with which I use the data to populate a table with a Datatable as follows:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    html.Append("<tr>");
     foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
     {
        html.Append("<td>");
        html.Append("<a target='_blank' href= " + "'" + row[dt.Columns["subCategoryURL"]] + "'" + " >");
        html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
        html.Append("</a>");
        html.Append("</td>")
     }
    html.Append("</tr>");
}
```

I currently have the SP return 2 columns of information: subCategoryName, subCategoryDescription. I wanted to added a 3rd column subCategoryURL which would serve as an  tag for a link as below:

```
<td>
   <a target="_blank" href="#">Dealer Support</a>
</td>
<td>
   <a target="_blank" href="#">Support information for dealer management</a>
</td>
```

How would I target each column specifically to build the table? I attempted to use `html.Append(row[dt.Columns["subCategoryURL"]]);`
 but it did not return the desired result. What could I do next?

Comment: Are you sure that the column in `DataTable` is named exactly `subCategoryURL`? Because what you did should work.

Comment: The subcategory URL ended up in the table...how would I target the other 2 to in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The subcategory URL ended up in the table...how would I target the other 2 to in the loop

The same way, i.e.:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
 html.Append("<tr>");
 html.Append("<td>");
 html.Append("<a target='_blank' href= " + "'" + row["subCategoryURL"].ToString() + "'" + " >");
 html.Append(row["subCategoryName"].ToString());
 html.Append("</a>");
 html.Append("</td>");

 html.Append("<td>");
 html.Append(row["subCategoryDescription"].ToString());
 html.Append("</td>");

 html.Append("</tr>");
}
```

row["**subCategoryName**"] will get you the value of the "**subCategoryName**" column of the current row.

Answer (score 1):

To get an item of a specific Type (T) from a DataRow (datarow) corresponding to a specific column (columnName), you can use the following.

```
dataRow.Field<T>(columnName)
```

So,

```
string url = row.Field<string>(subCategoryURL)
```

may work.

Keep in mind that T must be of the same type as the data stored in the specified column of the DataRow.  Should subCatergoryURL point to a row of doubles, the above would throw an InvalidCastException.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: you should specify that the `row.Field<T>` should correspond to the correct datatype of the specific datatable column as well otherwise the `OP` might take verbatim what you are stating.